# Error after upgrading Magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.5 match

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade, composer, vendor

```
syntax error, unexpected token "match", expecting variable#0 /httpdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(432): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::Composer\Autoload\{closure}()
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#2 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Relations/Runtime.php(38): class_exists()
#3 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(157): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime->has()
#4 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(180): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->_inheritInterception()
#5 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(213): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->hasPlugins()
#6 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(190): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->generateIntercepted()
#7 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(122): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->initializeUncompiled()
#8 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->__construct()
#9 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
#10 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#11 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/Environment/Developer.php(84): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#12 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(191): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer->configureObjectManager()
#13 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create()
#14 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(127): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->__construct()
#15 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create()
#16 /httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(85): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->initObjectManager()
#17 /httpdocs/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct()
#18 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check these things before upgrading :

```
- Composer version
- PHP version 
- Update all PHP extensions
```